# GIF White Outline

Tags: html, gif

I was wondering if there's a way to remove the white outline on a GIF on my website.

[Here](http://uploads.webflow.com/559af9ae30c483ec74512c38/54f4ca1edced7ed62ba934b4_infinite-gif-preloader.gif)

Is there any way to remove it? Or would I have to do this during creation of the GIF?

Regards, Owen.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that GIF has been saved with transparent background, and its half-transparent edges having a white background.

If you still have the GIF and something like Photoshop, try to set its background color to the color you are using in the webpage and save it again.

Comment: As  I wrote: If you have the original file and an app like Photoshop (which allows to choose a background color for transparency), that's possible. If not, it won't be.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the added white on the image, and then saving it as a PNG file. I know that works with images, so it will probably work for this. If you save it in a folder or a desktop, it will look like it still has the white background. But when you open that new file in Photoshop, you'll see it's gone.

So if when you put it on your website, the background will be clear.

Does this help? :)

Comment: It is a gif, an animated picture.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you do not have Photoshop, and are unable to do that, I'd be more than happy to do it for you. Just let me know and I'll give you a temporary email address to send it to me, and I'll send it back to you :)